# Property 'uuid' not found on object of type 'CBPeripheral *'

Tags: ios, core-bluetooth, uuid, nsuuid

I am using the following code:

```
CFStringRef cfstr = CFUUIDCreateString(NULL, self.peripheral.uuid);
```

This returns an error of

> "Property 'uuid' not found on object of type 'CBPeripheral *'"

I think this is because `uuid` has been deprecated but I am not sure how to correct it.

I have tried changing `self.peripheral.uuid` to `self.peripheral.identifier` but this then gives me

> 'incompatible pointer types passing retainable parameter of type
>   'NSUUID *' to CF Function expecting 'CFUUIDRef' (aka 'const struct
>   __CFUUID *') type

please help if you can.

Comment: `CFStringRef cfstr = CFUUIDCreateFromString(NULL, (__bridge CFStringRef)peripheral.identifier.UUIDString);` ?

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to get the `peripheral`'s UUID as a `CFStringRef`, then all you need to do is:

`CFStringRef cfstr = (__bridge CFStringRef)peripheral.identifier.UUIDString;`

The `identifier` property on `CBPeripheral` is a `NSUUID` class object, which has a method that returns a `NSString` representation of the UUID.

See the class reference for more info: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSUUID_Class/